# Can't complete complicated query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a question about an SQL in C# I want to implement but I'm a bit stuck. Below are the tables with some example data:

**Student**:

```
(PK)tagID  studentID (FK)courseID
4855755    HUJ564334    25
4534664    RED231232    33
```

**Course**

```
(PK)courseID courseName
25           Computer Science
33           Biology
```

**CourseModule**

```
(FK)courseID (FK)moduleID
25              CMP2343
25              CMP3456
33              BIO3422
33              BIO2217
```

**Module**

```
(PK)moduleID moduleName
CMP2343      Networking
CMP3456      Databases
BIO3422      Human body
BIO2217      Genetics
```

**ModuleSession**

```
(FK)moduleID (FK)sessionID
CMP2343      1ACMP2343
CMP2343      2ACMP2343 
CMP3456      1ACMP3456
CMP3456      2ACMP3456
BIO3422      1ABIO3422      
BIO3422      2ABIO3422
BIO2217      1ABIO2217      
BIO2217      2ABIO2217
```

**Session**

```
(PK)sessionID sessionStartDate sessionTimeStart sessionTimeEnd
1ACMP2343      09/05/2013          12:00 AM         14:00 PM
2ACMP2343      05/05/2013          09:00 AM         11:00 PM
1ACMP3456      15/05/2013          12:00 AM         13:00 PM
2ACMP3456      01/05/2013          10:00 AM         13:00 PM
1ABIO3422      30/04/2013          11:00 AM         13:00 PM
2ABIO3422      01/04/2013          14:00 AM         16:00 PM
1ABIO2217      12/05/2013          16:00 AM         18:00 PM
2ABIO2217      03/05/2013          12:00 AM         14:00 PM
```

**Attendance**

```
(FK)tagID (FK)sessionID scanningTime
```

I am using RFID scanner to scan the student `tagID`. I would like my query to find a "current" `sessionID` (by looking up the date and time of the session, saved in DB) for the given `tagID`, and display `TagID` and `SessionID` in the `Attendance` table, along with the time of scanning.

So to achieve this I need to:

- Look at what the `Student` table and get the `TagID`
- See which course this `tagID` is associated with (looking at `CourseID` column)
- Look at `CourseModule` table to see what modules are associated with the course
- Look at `ModuleSession` table to see what sessions are associated with the module
- Look at `Session` table to check which `sessionID` is happening "today and now"
- Display `tagID` and `sessionID` in `Attendance` table

So if I want to find the current session for the `tagID = 4855755`, then the `Attendance` output should be:

**Attendance**:

```
    (FK)tagID (FK)sessionID scanningTime
     4855755    1ACMP2343
```

This is because:

- Looking at `Student` table: student 4855755 is on courseID = 25
- Looking at `CourseModule` table: courseID = 25 compromises of two modules: CMP2343 and CMP3456
- Looking at `ModuleSession` table: modules CMP2343 and CMP3456 compromise of 2 sessions each: 1ACMP2343; 2ACMP2343 and 1ACMP3456; 2ACMP3456
- Looking at `Session` table: only session 1ACMP2343 is taking place today and now

My question is how is the query suppose to be written to be able to achieve the example mentioned above? I have made a start on the query but I need some help to get it working as it should be.

Code is:

```
SELECT Student.tagID, Session.sessionID 
FROM Student s , Session se
INNER JOIN Course c ON c.courseID = s.courseID
INNER JOIN CourseModule cm ON cm.courseID = c.courseID
INNER JOIN Module m ON m.moduleID = cm.moduleID
INNER JOIN ModuleSession ms ON ms.moduleID = cm.moduleID
INNER JOIN Session se ON se.sessionID = ms.sessionID
INNER JOIN Attendance a ON a.sessionID = se.sessionID 
WHERE Student.tagID = 4820427
AND s.SessionDate=DATE();
```

(updated) C# code of my class is:

```
    public void setSQL()
        {
            string ConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Kacper\\Desktop\\AutoReg\\AutoReg\\AutoReg.accdb;";`

            OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);
            MyConn.Open();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            //query to ask
            string query = @"SELECT s.TagID, se.SessionID, " + "'" + 
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss tt") + @"' AS scanningTime 

                            FROM Student s,
                            CourseID-ModuleID cm,
                            ModuleID-SessionID ms,
                            Session se

                            WHERE 1=1 
                            AND s.TagID = 4820427
                            AND s.CourseID = cm.CourseID
                            AND ms.ModuleID = cm.ModuleID
                            AND ms.SessionID = se.SessionID
                            AND se.SessionDate = Date();";

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, MyConn);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);

                adapter.Fill(ds);
                dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                MyConn.Close();

        }
```

I have updated my SQL code but still cannot get it running, I get and error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).

Comment: Just to clarify everything. Your question is about to write the SQL query to retrieve that information from your SQL Server Database? Not in particularly C#..

Comment: [Should I include tags in titles ?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) : No. You should not.

Comment: What's the issue with your current query, other than removing the first `Session se` after `FROM` and I don't think you want `s.SessionDate` but `se.SessionDate` closer to the end, right? And, as @gustavodidomenico mentions, there's nothing particularly C#-related about this question, I don't think.

Comment: OK, I use this query inside the C# application that retrives information from local database from Access (not SQL Server DB)

Comment: Never mix implict and explicit joins, they can often give teh wornfg answer as in many database the explicit joins are evaluated first. In fact you should never use implicit joins at all as they are a SQL antipattern that casues porblems and makes the code harder to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make your C# easier to read, you might want to use the "@" convention to insert newlines.  I'm going to cheat for the third field -- I think you want the output to be the time you ran the query.

```
query = @"SELECT s.tagID, se.sessionID, " + 
    "'" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss tt") + @"' AS scanningTime 
    FROM Student s
    INNER JOIN Course c ON c.courseID = s.courseID
    INNER JOIN CourseModule cm ON cm.courseID = c.courseID
    INNER JOIN Module m ON m.moduleID = cm.moduleID
    INNER JOIN ModuleSession ms ON ms.moduleID = cm.moduleID
    INNER JOIN Session se ON se.sessionID = ms.sessionID
    INNER JOIN Attendance a ON a.sessionID = se.sessionID 
    WHERE Student.tagID = 4820427
    AND se.SessionDate=DATE()";
```

There are actually a few ways to clean this up, I think.  Do you need any value from Course?  If not, drop that join.  Same with module and module session.

```
query = @"select s.tagID, ms.sessionId, " + 
    "'" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss tt") + @"' AS scanningTime 

    from student s,
    coursemodule cm,
    modulesession ms,
    session sess

    WHERE 1=1
    and s.tagID = 4820427
    and s.courseId = cm.courseId
    and ms.moduleId = cm.moduleId
    and ms.sessionId = sess.sessionId
    and sess.sessionStartDate = Date()";
```

Note that your SQL has an extra `Session se` in the same line as `FROM Student s` and has `s.SessionDate` instead of `se.SessionDate`.

Try blasting the comment in the second SQL; it's been a long time since I've thrown SQL at Access.

Past that, you're probably moving on to a different question.  Try the standard debugging moves -- can you run a simpler query, like `query = "SELECT * FROM Student";` from the same spot without the error?

Comment: Sorry, my bad... scanningTime is not a foreign key, its just a field

Comment: Which table owns `scanningTime`?  Looking at your SQL from the C# code, you've still got an extra `Session se` in there and `s.SessionDate` at the end, which should be `se.SessionDate`.

Comment: Is there a way to input this query to VS in your format? I get Newline in constant error...

Comment: Attendance table owns scanning time field

Comment: For the newline bit, use the `@"your string here"` convention -- notice the `@` before the first quote.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the new query, but I get an error An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).

Comment: Depending on when you grabbed the SQL, I may have had a missing comma -- ah, and I have full names in the first query where I shouldn't.

Comment: I have checked the query but cannot find anything wrong about it, yet, still doesn't work :/

Comment: And yes, I can run a simple query, but not this one

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get this query work. It needed square brackets around the table names.

```
string query = @"SELECT s.TagID, se.SessionID, '" + 
           DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss tt") + 
           "' AS scanningTime " + 
           "FROM (((Student s " + 
           " LEFT JOIN [CourseID-ModuleID] cm ON s.CourseID = cm.CourseID) " + 
           " LEFT JOIN [ModuleID-SessionID] ms ON ms.ModuleID = cm.ModuleID) " + 
           " LEFT JOIN [Session] se ON ms.SessionID = se.SessionID) " + 
           "WHERE s.TagID = 4820427 AND se.SessionDate = Date()";
```

Comment: Argh.  [Khan!!](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?s=99a1fee50e2a367b45f35a90ae985647&showtopic=1769126&view=findpost&p=1769143) But I think it's because of the hyphens; the above link says if you don't have "special characters", the brackets aren't necessary.  Those (eg, `CourseID-ModuleID`) weren't the names you originally gave us, right?  You also went `LEFT JOIN` on us; were there values that didn't map?  Sounds like it was fun.  Glad you got it to work!